# how to load custom properties in application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, application.properties

In spring boot , there is an property file application.property, along with this property , I have created an extra property file named myownprop.properties.

How can I load `myownprop.properties` in `application.property`? means how to include another named properties in application.properties?

any update ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `spring.config.additional-location` property as described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files. It allows you to add additional files without messing with the nice default hierarchy of property sources that Spring Boot defines.

Answer (score -1):

You could add a new active profile in your current application.properties

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: dev, additional
```

and then add a new application-additional.properties file in your resource folder. The entries within the new file are then available as they are in the application.properties.